# Variable scope in Bash

Tags: bash, process, pipe

The following bash does not print out var `text`, which is confusing to me. How to print the value of `text`?

```
text=D
echo -e 'A\nB\nC' | while read aline; do
text=$aline 
done
echo $text
```

the printout is `D`, but I want to print value `C`.

Comment: BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: On a side note, `printf '%s\n' A B C` is the better way to print the given stream; any shell in which `echo -e` does something other than print `-e` on its output is explicitly violating the POSIX spec.